# How to make dynamic textarea in CActiveForm in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to make text area in cactiveform in yii dynamically. but I am getting error i.e. "Property "Verse.translation" is not defined"

I have `translation_text` field, not `translation` field in my db. Secondly `$trans['translation_text']` display the verse translation but when i keep it in textArea it is giving error. as i have described.

I have a code.

```
<?php foreach($model->verseTranslations as $trans) { ?>
<?php $model->translation = $trans['translation_text']; ?>
<?php echo $form->textArea($model,'translation',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But i do not know how to keep value `$trans['translation_text']` in textArea.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I am getting errors" is not very informative. Be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
<?php foreach($model->verseTranslations as $trans) { ?>
<?php echo $form->textArea($model,'translation',array('value'=>$trans['translation_text'],'rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And in your model as RobM said earlier, but don't forget to add a validator in you Verse class for 'translation' attribute ! :

```
class Verse extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $translation;
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(   
                   array(
                           'translation',
                           'safe',
                           'on'=>'',
                    ),
                    //others validators here
                );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the second parameter in `$form->textArea` with `$trans['translation_text']`, so that it becomes:

```
<?php echo $form->textArea($model, $trans['translation_text'], array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
```

The second parameter is the value of the textArea, so the value of any variable here will show up as the default value of the text area element.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem then. Please explain more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Add translation property to Verse class in models

```
class Verse extends CActiveRecord
{
        public $translation;
```

Comment: How I add translation property to the Verse Class ?

Comment: *edit added + are you sure that you have 'translation' field in database?